# using Calculated Fields Form plugin

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I'm using 'Calculated Fields Form' plugin for WordPress.
I have already created my form but it is not a premium version and I have to use HTML , CSS and JQuery to build a php file to email my customers request to my email .
my php file :

```html
$computers = $_POST['fieldname2_1'];
$servers = $_POST['fieldname3_1'];
$branches = $_POST['fieldname4_1'];
$support = $_POST['fieldname5_1'];
$price = $_POST['fieldname1_1'];
$name = $_POST['fieldname7_1'];
$email = $_POST['fieldname12_1'];
$phone = $_POST['fieldname8_1']; 
$to = 'danialskh@yahoo.com';
$subject = 'network supporting request';
$message = 'FROM: '.$name.' Email: '.$email.'Message: '.$message;
$headers = 'From: danialskh@yahoo.com' . "\r\n";
if (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) { // this line checks that we have a valid email address
 mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers); //This method sends the mail.
    echo "درخواست شما ارسال شد !"; // success message
 }else{
     echo "ایمیل اشتباه است ! لطفا ایمیل صحیح را وارد کنید .";
  }
```

and I have this in my  :

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#fieldname11_1").click(function(){
    $("#cp_calculatedfieldsf_pform_1").attr("action", "http://ariyannet.com/module/wp-content/themes/twentyseventeen/networkcustomer.php");
 $("#fieldname13_1").attr("type", "submit");
    $("#field_1-6").fadeIn(1000);
});
$("#fieldname14_1").click(function(){
    $("#field_1-6").fadeOut(1000);
});
$('#fieldname13_1').click(function() {
         $('#fieldname13_1').attr('value', 'لطفا صبر کنید ...');
         $.post("http://ariyannet.com/module/wp-content/themes/twentyseventeen/networkcustomer.php", $("#cp_calculatedfieldsf_pform_1").serialize(), function(response) {
             $('#fieldname15_1').html(response);
             $('#fieldname13_1').attr('value', 'ارسال');
         });
         return false;
});
});
</script>
```

but when I click on submit button of form , nothing happens !!!
and if I don't use Jquery , after clicking on button , browser just shows me a raw version of my php file

anybody can help me ?

Comment: For starters check browser console for errors. Wordpress usually implements jQuery.noConflict() which makes `$` undefined and will throw error. As for the php showing up raw means it's not being compiled on server

Comment: @charlietfl thanks , I checked it but there is one more error in console :Failed to load https://ariyannet.com/module/wp-content/themes/twentyseventeen/networkcustomer.php: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://www.ariyannet.com' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: Are you running the above code on localhost server or opening in file protocol?

Comment: @charlietfl no , it's running on my host (Cpanel)

Comment: @charlietfl I used an extension and it worked but already it is showing me my raw code

Comment: Is it running on https? And you are trying to request to http as shown above?

Comment: @charlietfl yes , I had changed it before you said

Comment: So it works now?

Comment: @charlietfl unfortunately no :( it shows up raw

Comment: should really be using wordpress ajax endpoint and not creating your own. How to do it is well documented